# print elements using stream.foreach() does not work

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code and want to print the list elements after multiplying them my 10 but it says void is not allowed. How to solve it?

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(10,22,30); 

   long muliplied = integerList.stream()
                                .map(e -> e*10)
                                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What result do you expect for multiplied?

Comment: @harshavmb worked well.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch each of the elements to get multiplied by 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot save the result of the method, as its return type is void.

Try the following code

```
package eu.webfarmr;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class StreamExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(10, 22, 30);

        integerList.stream().map(e -> e * 10).forEach(System.out::println);


    }
}
```

The printed result is

```
100
220
300
```

Answer (score 5):

The `forEach` method of the `Stream` class takes a `Consumer` as an argument. A `Consumer` is one which accepts a parameter , but returns void. Now lets see one by one what each step returns:

`integerList.stream()`  returns a Stream

`.map(e -> e*10)` again returns a Stream

`.forEach(System.out::println);` returns a void

You are trying to assign this void to a long, so the compiler complains.